# Automatically show status after git add

Tags: git

My usual git workflow is

```
<make changes>
git add FILES
git status
git commit -m "some remarks"
```

where I need the `git status` just to check if I added the correct files.

Is there a way to tell `git` to automatically display the status after each `git add`?

Comment: You could probably create an alias that executes `add` first, and then `status`. E.g. `git config --global alias.ad "!git add $1; git status"`, but I’m not sure if you can keep supporting all the `add` parameters that way.

Answer (score 15):

When run with `-v` (verbose) option, `git add` outputs the name of files that were added:

```
» git add -v hello?
add 'hello1'
add 'hello2'
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use an [alias](http://git-scm.com/book/ch2-7.html):

```
[alias]
    gitadd = !sh -c 'git add -- "$@" && git status' --

make changes
$ git gitadd FILES
$ git commit -m "some remarks"
```

---

Since `git` aliases work from the repository root[<sup>1</sup>](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), you could modify the alias to make it work from any other directory:

```
[alias]
    gitadd = !sh -c 'cd "$1" && shift && git add -- "$@" && git status' --
```

Now invoke it by saying

```
git gitadd $PWD file1 file2 ...
```

[<sup>1</sup>](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):  Note that shell commands will be executed from the top-level directory of a repository, which may not necessarily be the current directory.

Comment: it would be `git gitadd` with that alias, imho

Comment: @devnull I added the above lines to ~/.gitconfig but when typing `git gitadd somefile` it says `Nothing specified, nothing added. Maybe you wanted to say 'git add .'?`

Comment: @flonk That's odd.  What if you say `$*` instead of `$@` in the alias.

Comment: @devnull Ooops, unfortunately it only works on the repository's root folder. i.e. `git gitadd somedir/somefile` works, but `git gitadd somefile` from inside `somedir`fails telling me `fatal: pathspec 'somefile' did not match any files`

Comment: @devnull What is even more strange, when doing `git gitadd somedir/somefile` from *inside* `somedir`, it works. Your solution seems to require filenames relative to the repository root.

Comment: @devnull couldn't one tell the alias to `cd` to the place from which it was called before performing `git add ...`?

Comment: @flonk Figured a workaround.  Modify the alias to `gitadd = !sh -c 'cd $1 && shift && git add -- "$@" && git status' --` and invoke it by saying `git gitadd $PWD file1 file2 ...`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I have using the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/26243454 and combining it with [devnull's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17969370):

```
[alias]
    sadd = !sh -c 'cd -- ${GIT_PREFIX:-.} && git add -- "$@" && git status' --
```

This way you don't need to pass in the working directory manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via creating an alias that executes `add first and then status` using `git config` commnad ..