# correct syntax for a .gitconfig alias to git add all files and then git commit -m?

Tags: git

I've lost my `.gitconfig` aliases in an OS reload on my machine and I failing to set up and alias for a command that I used to run on my old machine.

I used to run `git commit -am 'commit message here'` in terminal and it would add all files for me, `git add .`, and then `git commit -m` for me with the string given to the alias `-am` command passed in as the commit message. How should I correctly set up and alias to recreate this behaviour on my new machine?

I've played around with various syntax, such as:

```
am = "git add . && git commit -m"
```

or
am = "!git add . && git commit -m"

But these are not working so must be incorrect. Can anyone advise as to how best to do this? Thanks

Comment: `git add .` is considered harmful, and will eventually result in adding files or changes you didn't mean to add. Paired with an automatic `git commit -m` is particularly problematic. You should instead use `git add -p` or `git add -i`, and take the time to review the changes you're adding.

Comment: `git commit -am` still works. Note that it's roughly equivalent to using `git add -u`, *not* `git add .`; these two are very different. If you want to use two separate Git commands, you need the `!` form of the alias. I personally recommend avoiding `git commit -a` (with or without `-m`) and being very careful with `git add .` (see @meagar's comment).

Comment: Thanks for the word of warning on `git add` @meagar. And thanks for the `git commit` info @torek. All points noted and I shall now read up and learn more about these git flags and amend my workflow. On reflection and in light of your info, i think that perhaps I was previously using `git add .` then `git commit -am`, not an alias as i thought I may have been. I'll leave this post here in case it might help guide anyone else use git more safely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use `git add .`, you can define a [`.bashrc` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66207236/6309) or a [git  alias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4299159/6309).

But as noted, especially with `git add .`, it is always best to do a `git status` and double-check what you are actually adding to your index, *before* making any commit.

You can therefore consider another alias to [Automatically show status after git add](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53654984/6309).

```
[alias]
    sadd = !f() { cd -- "${GIT_PREFIX:-.}" && git add -- "$@" && git status; }; f
```

- The `!` is to execute an external command (here a function `f` in the same shell, faster than `!sh '...'` which starts a subshell), as mentioned in [Git Aliases](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases).
- `${GIT_PREFIX:-.}` uses the environment variable `GIT_PREFIX` value, if set, or '`.`' if not ([bash parameter expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2013589/6309)).
  As I explain in "[Get the path where git alias was run from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31722425/6309)":

> If `GIT_PREFIX` is *not* defined (because you are executing the alias from the root folder of the repo), it will be replaced by '`.`'.
> When you execute an alias from the *root folder*, `GIT_PREFIX` is not defined. Hence the need to use '`.`' (current folder).

- Once you are at the Git repository root folder, `git add -- "$@"` will add everything (if no parameters passed), or only what you pass as parameters (`"$@"`).

Comment: Thank you @VonC. Any chance you could you provide a bit of explanation to the syntax in this command?

Comment: @jbk Sure. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @chepner Good point. I have edited the answer accordingly (again).

Comment: @chepner And thank you for the edit. I swear I usually always add double-quotes, abiding by https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086.

Comment: Thanks @VonC, very helpful.